# How to close individual tabs in VB.NET tabcontrol

Tags: vb.net, tabs, tabcontrol

I have a tabcontrol in VB.Net, How to implement a it so that it has an 'X' for closing a single tab?

Comment: There is no out of the box way of doing this. Either you will have to intercept the painting of the tabs and draw your own X or use a third party control

Comment: Use the DrawMode property and implement the DrawItem event to draw the tab.  And MouseDown to detect a click on the X.